# I used elk+redis+filebeat to build the logging platform, and now after redis is replaced by codis, logstash reports？？？

Tags: logging, redis, logstash, elk

I used elk+redis+filebeat to build the logging platform, and now after redis is replaced by codis, logstash reports:

```
# [2020-06-18T11:20:54,146][WARN ][logstash.inputs.redis] Redis connection problem {:exception=>#<Redis::CommandError: ERR handle request, command'BLPOP' is not allowed>} 


# [2020-06-18T11:19:12,920][WARN ][logstash.inputs.redis] Redis connection problem {:exception=>#<Redis::CommandError: ERR max number of clients reached>}strong text
```

This is my logstash configuration:

## /usr/local/elk/logstash/config/logstash_es.conf

```
input {
  redis {
     data_type => "list"
     key => "elk"
     host => "192.168.124.224"
     port => "19000"
     batch_count => "1"
     threads => 5
     codec => "json"
     }
}

output {
    if [fields][log_type] == "php" {
          elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["192.168.124.225:9200"]
                index => "php-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                action =>  "index"
                }
               }
}
```

Comment: Aren't the errors clear enough? Have you tried a redis-cli to check whether the commands are in fact forbidden? Have you looked at the number of clients connected? This question lacks quite a bit of research as it stands...

Answer (score 0):

Codis mentions they are 100% compatible with twemproxy. [according to the twemproxy documentation](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/blob/master/notes/redis.md#lists) the `BLPOP` command is not supported. Because the [logstash Redis input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.8/plugins-inputs-redis.html#_description_36) describes `BLPOP` as a required function, this tells me that Codis can't be used with Logstash at all.